# Facebook Apps: Is there any way for facebook storing the Application history?

Tags: facebook

I've just started with facebook application development and seems to be very excited about it. While doing my research over the facebook app development, i just got this thought - Can facebook app store all the applications history form the day the App went live? Can facebook do this? And can we as a developer retrieve the history?

Comment: I am not sure about that but history like what happened on this particular date who all used the app and what all activities they did and all that stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [facebook insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/)

> Use Insights for your app to track how users are interacting with your
>   app to build the best possible experience for your users. For app
>   administrators, Insights includes feedback for stream stories,
>   referral traffic to your app, a breakdown of what user actions
>   contribute to active user count, demographics on authorized users and
>   active users, and the number of times permissions are prompted and
>   granted.
>
> Detailed Insights on Open Graph activity for your app is also
>   available.
>
> In addition, it provides diagnostics for your app so that you can
>   track API errors as well as get access to allocations and throttling
>   information.
>
> You can access Insights for your app directly through the Insights
>   Dashboard or by selecting your app in the developer app and clicking
>   the “insights" link

Comment: This is so cool...! Does facebook store app history internally ?